# Google Code email notification

Tags: svn, notifications, google-code

I have a question with regards Google Code svn repositories.

Is there a way no be notified by email when someone on your team does a commit ?

I have been looking around, but I can't find the way to activate this option (if it exists).
Thanks for any help given.

Comment: I can't log in to a Google Code project right now, but I'm pretty sure it's a simple checkbox somewhere - at least if you're the project's owner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need for a Post-Commit hooks, Google Code has this feature built-in. Go to the *Administer* > *Source* tab and then fill the email address of the *Activity notifications*  (usually, a mailing list address).

Comment: How about if I want all the members of my team to receive such notification?

Comment: You need SMTP e-mail alias or post directly to the mailing list's address.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to use google's [PostCommitWebHook](http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/PostCommitWebHooks) to set something up if nothing already exists...

Answer (score 0):

There's also an rss feed URI in the header of the Project Home -> Updates tab. Safari (and I assume Firefox) exposes it, or you can extract it from the page source.

Answer (score 0):

**First, you must be the owner of the project**: If you are the owner choose *Administer* tab option from main menu of the project, then choose *Source* option. Scroll down and search for *Activity notifications* section and enter the email address.

If using Google Groups, enable "Anyone can post" messages in your googlegroup configuration.